# How to set advaced printing options when using "lpr" to print?

Tags: ubuntu, printing, pdf

On ubuntu Hardy 8.04, some PDF files have printing issues - they take forever to print, all this while evince (the PDF reader) uses 100% CPU. After that, the actual print comes out very blurry and unreadable.

I usually use pdf2ps to convert them to a postscript file that prints without any issues, but that's not always the case.

In those cases when the ps come garbled, I use lpr to send the pdf directly to the printer - the problem is that I don't know how to set 2 sided printing with lpr.

I print enough PDFs for these edge cases to matter, and having this command line option will also allow me to use a script I once wrote that takes a URL as input and sends it to the printer.

Does anyone here know how to set this 2 sided printing option from the command line? man lpr shows that it has a -o=options flag, but I cannot find the relevant option for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google search for "lpr double sided" found out [this page](http://webscript.princeton.edu/~pug/faqwiki/index.php?title=Printing_to_OIT_printers).

```
 lpr -o sides=two-sided-long-edge foo.ps
```

Comment: It works!

Thank you very much!